# Directory disappear suddenly, but detected with ls

Tags: directory, external-hdd

So, i have a external hard drive and it is working normally, until suddenly i realize (when using windows) that some directory is missing.
so I tried to access my external hard drive using ubuntu (nautilus) but get same result, so i try using terminal "ls -l" and get this result.

```
ls: cannot access 'MIGRASI': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'MOVIES': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'msdownld.tmp': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'mtasolo.zip': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'MUSIK': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'PICTURE': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'replace_script.sh': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'replace_sql.sh': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'TO DO': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'udbdudsn': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Untitled Folder': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Untitled Folder 2': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'vcredist.bmp': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'VC_RED.cab': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'VC_RED.MSI': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'VIDEO TUTORIAL': No such file or directory
total 1224957
drwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief          0 Okt 24 23:46 aaa
drwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief          0 Nov 18 21:09 BACKUP FLASHDISK
drwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief       4096 Nov 28 12:44 BACKUP HP
drwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief       4096 Nov 28 13:04 BACKUP bbb
-rwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief   17706095 Jan  4 10:18 coba.sql
drwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief      20480 Jan 14 19:14 DOKUMEN
-rwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief        472 Jan 17 03:40 export.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief   64648061 Nov  2 10:32 fixH-1.zip
-rwxrwxrwx 2 arief arief 1171811715 Jan 16 14:36 flashdisk.rar
drwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief          0 Okt 24 18:48 GAME ROMS
drwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief      16384 Jan 23 22:34 ccc
-rwxrwxrwx 2 arief arief     134313 Jan 16 14:47 ddd 2016.xlsx
d????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? MIGRASI
d????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? MOVIES
d????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? msdownld.tmp
-????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? eee.zip
d????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? MUSIK
d????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? PICTURE
drwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief       4096 Jan 21 01:09 $RECYCLE.BIN
-????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? replace_script.sh
-????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? replace_sql.sh
drwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief          0 Jan 23 22:34 System Volume Information
drwxrwxrwx 1 arief arief          0 Jan 23 22:34 System Volume Information
d????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? TO DO
d????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? udbdudsn
d????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? Untitled Folder
d????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? Untitled Folder 2
-????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? VC_RED.cab
-????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? vcredist.bmp
-????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? VC_RED.MSI
d????????? ? ?     ?              ?            ? VIDEO TUTORIAL
```

And actually those are my missing directory.

I have tried using chown, or try to cp it but it is all fail.
please help me..

Comment: It is either your mount that was done incorrectly or you have a filesystem error. Is it NTFS? Or EXT? If the latter run a fschk on it. edit: oh looks like NTFS (recylce.bin ;) ). file check from windows might fix it

Comment: i formated it using NTFS,
how i can file check from windows?
i just tried using recuva from windows but i still cant recover what im looking for.
any advice?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has same problem with me:
I finally can recover my data using `getDataBack For NTFS`